# Qual è il significato di “tragliatta”?

Tags: word-meaning

Sto cercando di tradurre il seguente testo (preso [qui](https://books.google.com/books?id=bLIM7QP6A-EC&pg=PR17&lpg=PR17&dq=tragliatta&source=bl&ots=Ozfenr0kog&sig=3fNIY0M8nJ4Nb1vsi4-BMrfd_qs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjrk7ecuenOAhWEvxQKHUwmD-gQ6AEINzAE#v=onepage&q=tragliatta&f=false) da Google Books), e non riesco a capire il significato della parola **tragliatta**:

> Io dunque in tal caso, e da tale altezza posso chiaramente osservare il fondo, notare la di lui varietà, ed innoltre discernere quali corpi ivi si ritrovino; quando però egli sia solamente, o sassoso, o ghiaioso, poichè allora è assai limpido, e cristallino; ma per lo contrario essendo pantanoso, o arenoso, come accade al golfo di Venezia, l'acque sono alquanto torbide, nè permettono il vederci molto profondamente. Allora dunque volendo raccogliere o l'uno, o l'altro di que' corpi, lo fo con facilità, valendomi di una *Tanaglia* alta due piedi, e di mascella ben grande, di cui un braccio nella sommità è inanellato ad una lunga asta di legno, a cui altre, occorrendo, aggiungere se ne ponno, e connettere. L'altro braccio della Tanaglia tiene un occhio alla sommità, a cui lego una funicella, che passando per una **tragliatta**, che sta affissa alla sommità del primo braccio, scorre per tutta la lunghezza di tutto l'aste. Questa Tanaglia sostenuta dall'asse per un solo braccio, necessariamente resta aperta: la immergo allora, ed al corpo che aver desidero, l'addatto; stiro la corda, chiudo la Tanaglia e sollevandola poi prendo, e stringo ciò che più mi aggrada.

Come si può capire dal contesto, una "tragliatta" è qualcosa per cui passa una funicella. Una versione francese traduce "tragliatta" come "poulie" (puleggia); ma è possibile che questa sia soltanto una supposizione sulla base del contesto. Sarei grato di informazione certe.

La parola compare solo una volta nel testo; forse è un errore di stampa.

(Sono inglese; scusate il mio italiano.)

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE! Potresti riportare un frammento del testo con questo vocabolo?

Comment: Io non ho mai sentito questa parola, e una rapida ricerca sui dizionari e su google ha portato solo questo: https://books.google.com/books?id=bLIM7QP6A-EC&pg=PR17&lpg=PR17&dq=tragliatta&source=bl&ots=Ozfenr0kog&sig=3fNIY0M8nJ4Nb1vsi4-BMrfd_qs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjrk7ecuenOAhWEvxQKHUwmD-gQ6AEINzAE#v=onepage&q=tragliatta&f=false , che sembra indicare che sia un termine tecnico (e forse arcaico) della marineria. Potrebbe essere collegato anche a traglia: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/draglia/ .

Comment: Denis, è questo testo (di Donati) che sto cercando di tradurre!

Comment: Ho aggiunto il testo e corretto la grammatica. Sentiti libero/a di annullare la modifica se ti sembra che io abbia frainteso.

Comment: Grazie.

Se Donati ha imparato la parola dai pescatori (come è più possibile) allora erano molto probabilmente pescatori veneziani , e la parola può appartenere al dialetto veneziano. Di cui non so assolutamente nulla ...

Comment: Per andare fino in fondo (e dato che io parlo il veneziano, ancorchè d'entroterra) ho controllato nel dizionario Boerio (liberamente disponible su archive.org https://archive.org/details/dizionariodeldi00boergoog ) ma non ho trovato niente di rilevante. La mia teoria per ora è che si tratti di un *taglietto*, scritto in modo bizzarro.

Comment: Credo che abbia ragione Denis: *tragliatta* è cognato di *traglia* o *draglia*. Il termine nautico italiano è *passante* o *occhiello di fissaggio*. Simile ad una puleggia, è un occhiello chiuso che obbliga la fune di chiusura del braccio della tenaglia a passare dal lato interno della stessa, in modo da trasmettere la tensione che la serra.

Comment: su un vecchio dizionario italiano ho trovato _traglia_ : "canapo disteso e fermo alle estremità sul quale scorrono oggetti inanellati, serve di sostegno e guida anche a bandiere, vele e sim."

Answer (score 2):

L'ipotesi più probabile sembra essere che si tratti di una variante del termine *traglia*

> **dràglia** (o **tràglia**) s. f. [dal fr. *draille*, *traille*, che è il lat. *tragŭla*, der. di *trahĕre* «tirare»]. – Nell’attrezzatura navale, cavo d’acciaio di varia sezione che, teso orizzontalmente su aste verticali (*candelieri*) o altri supporti, serve a sostenere sui ponti scoperti le tende o a costituire la ringhiera di protezione della battagliola, in sostituzione delle aste orizzontali o delle catenelle. Con riferimento ai grandi velieri di un tempo, il termine indica (secondo l’uso francese) il falso strallo, o strallo volante, impiegato per stendere, tra l’albero di trinchetto e quello di bompresso, alcune vele di taglio (falso fiocco, ecc.) che si aggiungono agli stralli prodieri.
>
> (*Dal [Vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/draglia/))*

Ho cercato anche nel dizionario Boerio di Veneto se per caso ci fossero parole simili, ma sono rimasto a bocca asciutta. Ho paura che si tratti di un termine tecnico caduto in disuso e non conservato in alcun dizionario. Anche l'onnisciente *Google Books* è in grado di fornire solo il passo che ha stimolato questa domanda.